# What Methodology To Implement For Insert Statements In Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

When inserting a lot of interrelated nested objects, is it best practice to first create and persist the inner entites as to respect the foreign key relationsihps and move up in the hierarchy or is it better to create all the objects with their inner objects and persist only the outer object? So far, I have experienced that when doing the latter, Entity Framework seems to be intelligently figuring out what to insert first with regard to the relationships. But is there a caveat that one should be aware of? The first method seems to me as the classical SQL logic whereas the latter seems to suit the idea of Entity Framework more.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about managing the risk of data corruption and ensuring that database is valuable.

When you persist the inner records first, you open yourself up to the possibility of bad data if the outer save fails. Depending on your application needs, orphaned inner records could be anywhere from a major problem to a minor annoyance.

When you save everything together, if a single record fails the entire save fails.

Of course, if the inner records are meaningful without the outer records (again, determined by your business needs) then you might be preventing the application from progressing.

In short: if the inner record is dependent on the outer, save together. If the inner is meaningful on its own, make the decision based on performance / readability.

---

Examples:

A `House` has meaning without a `Homeowner`. It would be acceptable to create a `House` on its own.

A `HSA` (Homeowner's Association) does not make sense without `Homeowner`s. These should be created together.

Obviously, these examples are contrived and become trivial when using existing data. For the purpose of this question, we're assuming that both are being created at the same time.